# Kotlin: Code inside lamda function is unreachable while using library written in java

Tags: android, kotlin

I have used an image picker library (written in Java). It provides the pick-result to the caller activity using the overridden function. As my caller activity is in kotlin, the overridden function gets converted into lambda function. But the code inside lambda function doesn't get executed. Is this a Java-to-Kotlin issue? Or is there a mistake in code?

Here is my code:

```
   UtilLib.getPhoto(this, ChooseType.REQUEST_ANY)
                .enqueue({ path ->
                    Picasso.with(applicationContext)
                            .load("file://$path")
                            .error(R.drawable.profile)
                            .resize(150, 150)
                            .into(ivProfilePic)
                })
```

Library link: https://github.com/VinayRathod/UtilLib

**Here is the Java Code also which will work perfectly(Java).**

```
            ChooseType chooseType =
                    ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_gallery)).isChecked() ? ChooseType.REQUEST_PICK_PICTURE :
                            ((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.choose_camera)).isChecked() ? ChooseType.REQUEST_CAPTURE_PICTURE :
                                    ChooseType.REQUEST_ANY;
            UtilLib.getPhoto(this, chooseType)
                    .enqueue(new OnImageChooserListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onImageChoose(String path) {
                            ivPath.setText("" + path);
                            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(new File(path)).into(iv);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to answer this question since your link does not include the actual source code of the library, so pointing out why the code does not execute would be pure guesswork.

Comment: I will check that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code like this :

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.util.Log
import com.vinay.utillib.UtilLib
import com.vinay.utillib.imagechooser.ChooseType

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            UtilLib.getPhoto(this, ChooseType.REQUEST_ANY)
                    .enqueue({ path ->
                        Log.d("ok", "executed: $path")
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

And it seems to work : 
 `D/ok: executed: /storage/emulated/0/bichooser/1530711668746.myimage.png`